# How to spawn threads to make multiple posts at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a .netcore 6 BackGroundService which pushes data from on-premise to a 3rd party API.

The 3rd party API takes about 500 milliseconds to process the API call.

The problem is that I have about 1,000,000 rows of data to push to this API one at a time. At 1/2 second per row, it's going to take about 6 days to sync up.

So, I would like to try to spawn multiple threads in order to hit the API simultaneously with 10 threads.

```
 var startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
 var batchSize = _config.GetValue<int>("BatchSize");
 using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
 {
       var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PlankContext>();

       var dncEntries = await context.PlankQueueDnc.Where(x => x.ToProcessFlag == true).Take(batchSize).ToListAsync();
        
      foreach (var plankQueueDnc in dncEntries)
      {
         var response = await _plankConnector.InsertDncAsync(plankQueueDnc);
         context.PlankQueueDnc.Update(plankQueueDnc);
      }
      await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Here is the code.  As you can see, it gets a batch of 100 records and then processes them one by one.  Is there a way to modify this so this line is not awaited?  I don't quite understand how it would work if it were not awaited.  Would it create a thread for each execution in the loop?

```
var response = await _plankConnector.InsertDncAsync(plankQueueDnc);
```

I am clearly not up to speed on threads as well as the esteemed @StephanCleary.

So suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: use "Task Parallel Library" in C#.  However, another thing you may need to consider is: the API may have a limit for how many requests from one IP, etc. which means it can only process # calls for you at certain time.

Comment: @urlreader the OP is already using the TPL - async/await are part of it

Comment: The 3rd Party provider has not given us any information about an API limit, so that part is going to be trial and error.

Comment: Which .NET Core runtime are you using? In .NET (Core) 6 you could easily use `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to execute multiple operations concurrently. A DbContext can only be used by one thread though, and is probably the *wrong* library to use just to record a request.

Comment: Yes, using .net Core 6

Comment: Why are you using `Update` after the API call? You haven't modified the record

Comment: Actually, the record is modified in the InsertDncAsync call.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the Parallel.ForEachAsync is what I was looking for.  If you want to post that as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: @PadroHenrique, your answer was actually quite good and what I actually used, and it is working great.  I would suggest undeleting your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 6 you can use Parallel.ForEachAsync to execute operations concurrently, using either all available cores or a limited Degree-Of-Parallelism.

The following code loads all records, executes the posts concurrently, then updates the records :

```
using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PlankContext>();

    var dncEntries = await context.PlankQueueDnc
                                  .Where(x => x.ToProcessFlag == true)
                                  .Take(batchSize)
                                  .ToListAsync();
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(dncEntries,async plankQueueDnc=>
    {
        var response = await _plankConnector.InsertDncAsync(plankQueueDnc);
        plankQueueDnc.Whatever=response.Something;
    };

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

There's no reason to call `Update` as a DbContext tracks the objects it loaded and knows which ones were modified. `SaveChangesAsync` will persist all changes in a single transaction

**DOP and Throttling**

By default, ParallelForEachAsync will execute as many tasks concurrently as there are cores. This may be too little or too much for HTTP calls. On the one hand, the client machine isn't using its CPU at all while waiting for the remote service. On the other hand, the remote service itself may not like or even allow too many concurrent calls and may even impose throttling.

The [ParallelOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions?view=net-6.0) class can be used to specify the degree of parallelism. If the API allows it, we could execute eg 20 concurrent calls :

```
var option=new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20};
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(dncEntries,options,async plankQueueDnc=>{...});
```

Many services impose a rate on how many requests can be made in a period of time. A (somewhat naive) way of implementing this is to add a small delay in the task worker code can take care of this :

```
var delay=100;
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(dncEntries,options,async plankQueueDnc=>{
    ...
    await Task.Delay(delay);
});
```

Comment: Changetracker could be turned off. By the way, whynot use Task.WhenAll? If it is a single-core machine, Parallel wil not be of much use.

Comment: @Silvermind don't close it then. As for `Task.WhenAll`, because you can't make 1M concurrent HTTP calls. Not even 500, without the client or server freezing up and the service provider blocking you. When you try to execute too many operations concurrently, you end up *reducing* throughput because the operations end up interfering and blocking each other. The server(s) have limited bandwidth, CPU cores and disk IO. *Throttling* actually *increases* throughput because it reduces the number of operations that block each other